# Editing files in ubuntu with php or other language

Tags: php, python, ubuntu

is there any way I can edit my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default, create a directory and reload apache 2 through on  a website through php or any other script online on a ubuntu webserver?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: The file and string/regex functions are sufficient for that, given write permissions. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean through some kind of web interface that you are creating? Look into the `shell_exec` function. You can use it to create folders like `shell_exec('mkdir foldername')` and `shell_exec('/etc/init.d/apache2 restart')`

Comment: Yeah that is perfect. Had no idea you could do that.Cheers <3

Comment: Is it possible to append a config file with multiple lines with this function then please

Comment: Yes, look into the `cat` function. You can concatenate two files. Or simply `shell_exec('echo "test text" > file.txt')`